# Can Django's URL tag show the URL of the RedirectView

Tags: python, django, redirect, django-views, django-urls

Let's say that in my urls.py I have a url like this:

```
path("support/", RedirectView.as_view(url="http://www.example.com"), name="support"),
```

And in one of my templates I use the url tag:

```
{% url "support" %}
```

This of course outputs `/support/` as expected. But what if I want it to output `http://www.example.com` instead? Is that at all possible? Skip the redirect basically.

So `<a href="{% url "support" %}">Link</a>` would output `<a href="http://www.example.com">Link</a>`.

Answer (score 0):

> But what if I want it to render http://www.example.com instead? Is that at all possible? Skip the redirect basically.

No, in short it is not possible with django views, since the url is of another website and you can't render it in your own.

You can see what exactly [`render()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#render) does.

If you'd like to directly redirect, then simply use anchor tag as:

```html
<a href="http://www.example.com">Visit website.</a>
```

You can also do this dynamically, by creating a [`URLField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/fields/#urlfield) in one of the models and simply iterating it with `href` attribute of anchor tag.

Comment: I think my usage of the word "render" might have caused some confusing. I don't want to render the output of the website inside my own. I clarified my question. But yeah pretty sure it's not possible. Of course I know of all the other solutions, but I am specifically wondering about this for.. reasons :)

Comment: @kevinRenskers ya, I understood, but it's also not possible that after clicking a button which contians `support` url would output this `<a href="http://www.example.com">Link</a>.` as you mentioned in the question, if you click on it it simply redirects you on that particular url.